# Are there new expected dates for release of Groovy and Hydro distros?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, update, release, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this because in http://www.ros.org/wiki/Distributions info has not been updated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49628/are-there-new-expected-dates-for-release-of-groovy-and-hydro-distros?/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Expect Groovy release one of these days, and the given date for Hydro should still remain as planned, making Hydro more of a patch release.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2